# "2 Answers", but there is currently only one

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, deleted-answers

On [a certain question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917124/beautiful-soup-returning-nothing), I put up an answer and then deleted it when I realised it was the wrong solution. I believe someone else had also done this (I'm not 10k rep, so I can't check). So this is what appears for me:

[image]

But why does it stil say "2 Answers" at the top? Should it not be only 1, because there is only one answer which has not been deleted?

Also, for you 10k rep users, does it show 3 Answers? Because there was another user who deleted an answer.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**You** can see 2 answers, the count is correct.

Anonyomous and < 10k see '1 Answer'.

[image: Anonymous answer count]

I, as +10K user, see '3 Answers', because there are indeed 2 deleted answers:

[image: 10k answer count]

Comment: Ah, that makes perfect sense. So the counter is what I can see...

Comment: @Haidro Yes, says "3 Answers" for me (10k+) due to the two deleted answers.

Comment: Thanks guys! I'll accept your answer when I can Martijn. Meta questions get answered very quickly...